# Merging login and registration pages in everyauth for express.js

Tags: node.js, express, everyauth

In the default everyauth setup for password authentication, login and registration pages are distinct. I tried merging the corresponding jade files and arranging the get/post register and login paths in my server file to be the same. Then I loaded the merged page and got the following error:

500 ReferenceError: /Users/eterna/Downloads/fame/views/index.jade:8 6| label(for=everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName) Login 7| input(type='text', name=everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName, value=userParams[everyauth.password.loginFormFieldName]) > 8| #email 9| label(for=everyauth.password.emailFormFieldName) Email 10| input(type='text', name='email', value=userParams['email']) 11| #password userParams is not defined .

I'm clearly going about this the wrong way. Is there a simple solution for putting login and registration on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading the code for the default setup.  Without looking at your code (because you didn't post it)  I can see from the error that it is tripping over line 7 because you are trying to access userParams, which doesn't exist for login, but it does exist for registering.  It appears the userParams just holds input that the user has entered in the fields, so that when there is a registration error, the text that the user has already inputted is placed into the form. (ie if they type in their email address, but their password is too short, register errors and will still have their email address in the input field)

The easiest way to combine register and login is client side.  You could 
1) have your one form on the page with two submit buttons - register & login.  Depending on what the user clicks, the form posts to different entry points.

2) create register and login tabs, so when you click register, you display the register form and when you click the login tab it switches to the other form

You could go down the path of making everyauth do this logic by overriding respondToLoginFail, so when it attempt to log the person in and fails, it rebuilds the request and makes a post call to the register path.  I wouldn't recommend it but it's possible to make it work.